# Creating Custom Object__c

Tags: custom-object, administration

According to Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_custom_object__c.htm) when creating a custom Object we need to add __c at the end of the string. Does it make any difference if when creating a custom Object we don't add the __c?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more details (and add relevant tags). Right now, it's hard to determine exactly what you're trying to do and it's very likely that you're taking this documentation out of its relevant context (or misinterpreting it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a custom object in the UI, you don't type in the `__c`; it will be added automatically. When you create a custom object in an API, you must include the `__c` in the `fullName` attribute. Failing to include it, or trying to include any other suffix (e.g. `__haha`) will result in a deployment error. Note that other suffixes are referenced for related custom objects, like `Object__Share` is an object's sharing table, and `Object__Tag` for an object's tags. This is why you can't specify the suffix or omit it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think when we Create custom we need to add `__c` to the Object,
After we create the Object i.e after saving, SF automatically appends `__c` to that Object

When creating a custom Object you just need to give the Name of the Object

for Example

If you add name as `School` after saving that Object SF will append `__c` To it

If you add `School__c` while creating the Object SF will still Append __c
so it would look like `School_c__c`

Its not up to us to add `__c` you save a custom record by Its name and SF Adds `__c`